# How to write several union select in one select in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, union

I need to design an interface which users can choose years then its months, the years might be several years and for each year several months could be selected, then I need to write a select statement to retrieve the data. I can do it by several select statements and union them. Is there any solution to write it in one select?

This screenshot shows the interface I need to design:

[image]

What I wrote is this:

```
select * 
from yearmonth 
where year = '1390' and month in ('1', '2')
union
select * 
from yearmonth 
where year = '1391' and month in ('3', '4')
union
select * 
from yearmonth 
where year = '1392' and month in ('5')
union
select * 
from yearmonth 
where year = '1393' and month in ('1', '2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by combining the conditions with the OR operator:

```
select * 
from yearmonth 
where 
  (year = '1390' and month in ('1', '2'))
  or
  (year = '1391' and month in ('3', '4'))
  or
  (year = '1392' and month in ('5'))
  or
  (year = '1393' and month in ('1', '2'))
```

For these conditions, the code could be simplified to:

```
select * 
from yearmonth 
where 
  (year in ('1390', '1393') and month in ('1', '2'))
  or
  (year = '1391' and month in ('3', '4'))
  or
  (year = '1392' and month = '5')
```

Comment: could be simplified - but the query is driven by user selections and writing the logic to examine all the selected options for this optimization is not trivial.

Comment: @SMor this is why I say *For these conditions...*